# Why is this not a valid usage of byref?

Tags: f#, byref

```
let iter2D (map: 'T byref -> unit) (arr: 'T[][]) =
    for y = 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
        let row = arr.[y]
        for x = 0 to row.Length - 1 do
            let mutable elem = arr.[y].[x]
            map &elem
```

The last line has: "The address of the variable 'elem' cannot be used at this point." What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In F# `'T byref` appears as a regular type, but under the cover, it is not - it corresponds to `ref` and `out` parameters in C# and those are special annotations on method arguments. This is why `'T byref` is a bit odd in F#.

I think you won't be able to use it through ordinary F# functions, because a function `T1 -> T2` is compiled as `FSharpFunc<T1, T2>` with a method `T2 Invoke(T1 arg)` - and you cannot pass the `byref` type to generics (as it is not a real type).

A workaround is to define your own delegate that has `byref` type:

```
type FastAction<'T> = delegate of 'T byref -> unit
```

With this, you can write `iter2D` that iterates directly over the array:

```
let iter2D (map:FastAction<'T>) (arr: 'T[][]) =
    for y = 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
        let row = arr.[y]
        for x = 0 to row.Length - 1 do
            map.Invoke(&arr.[y].[x])
```

The following will then mutate the value inside the array:

```
let arr = [| [| 0 |] |]
iter2D (FastAction(fun a -> a <- 10)) arr
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying that `byref` is not real type? Then what is [`MakeByRefType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.makebyreftype.aspx) returning? And what is [`IsByRef`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.isbyref.aspx) property for?

Comment: Yuk, `FastAction(fun bla ...)` causes 2 allocations... Seems like there's no way around it though, F# doesn't have a separate anonymous delegate syntax like C#.

Comment: @Asik they do since F# 4 or 5, there’s now auto conversion into delegates. However, this still won’t work with byref, as they cannot be captured by closures (obviously), and the compiler won’t detect you’re only using your lambda as a delegate.